# Get ajax value outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to pass a value out of a get jQuery function here is the example:

```
function a(){

   var test="";    

   $.get("js/getDATEinvoice.php?inv=" + invoice, function(html) {               
      test=html;            
   });

alert(test);
}
```

I have tried with returns and i just can not get the value...

I have to call the function inside a function so it can get the value and proceed doing stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `A` in `AJAX` stands for *asynchronous*. You can't get the value immediately after you start the ajax call because it isn't done yet. You need to access it inside a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$.get("js/getDATEinvoice.php?inv=" + invoice, function(html) {               
      test=html;  
      alert(test);          
   });
```

A in Ajax means asynchronous. Also the function isn't guaranteed to return something from the result when called.

Comment: cant i do anything else instead of alert?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to pass the variable out of the function... not alert neither write in the document

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your variable outside the function scope

```
 var your_Var = '';
 function yourFunc(){
      your_Var =1;

 };
 alert(your_Var);
```